# Where can I get healing items for the Asgore boss fight?

Tags: undertale

I am doing the Pacifist run and I am finally fighting Asgore. I have fought him 9 times so far without success because I used all of my healing items at Mettaton EX's fight besides except the Snow Piece, which I would like to save for when I go to the surface.

I have tried walking out of the castle area, but it seems to go in circles. Where can I get items for this fight? **No spoilers please.**

Comment: Do you have the temmie armor? That will also help, in addition to obtaining healing items from MTT Resort

Comment: No, I don't have it. Thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**There's nothing stopping you from leaving the final area before the Asgore fight.**

In fact, before the first attempt at the fight, Asgore even gives you an opportunity to go back for anything else you needed to do. I'm not sure how you're getting lost going back, since it's a completely linear path back to the Core other than the elevator shortcut.

Either take the first elevator you see and then continue south until you reach the elevator back to the Core, or ignore the elevators until there's nowhere left to walk. This will take you back to the end of the Core. The elevator just outside the Mettaton battle area will lead you back to the first room of the Core. Simply continue south from there to get back to MTT Resort, where you can find a shop, or continue out elsewhere for other shopping options or sidequest activities.

Comment: @TheUnicornMaster If you can afford them, heading back to Snowdin for Bicicles would be a wise choice - double the healing item for half the inventory space.

Comment: @Zibbobz Bicicles aren't very useful in tough boss fights because they take two turns to consume, and in between those turns you'll get hit more. The food available at the MTT Resort shop is much better for the Asgore fight (the Glamburgers alone heal more than both halves of a Bicicle). The main problem is cost.

Comment: The pan makes the biscicles heal 15 hp. That's close enough to a full heal when you only have 20 hp.

Comment: This answer is pretty good, especially the note about combining the Burnt Pan with Bicicles (only a great move in Pacifist, though), but I'd also add that if you eat the first Snowman Piece you can get a second, as long as you don't eat it right in front of the Snowman.  (On Genocide you can get a third without even eating the others first!)

Answer (score -1):

The items in the MMT Resort were very useful. Go there for healing items. I found legendary heroes especially helpful since they upped your attack. I also went all the way back to the turtle guy in the Waterfalls and bunny lady in Snowdin to get sea tea (makes you faster) and a bisicle (eat it twice therefore technically more health to regain). I filled the cracks with junk food from bratty and catty (also the instant noodles give way more hp with Asgore cause you eat them dry) I also used the frying pan which upped hp item 4 percent

Answer (score -1):

If you still have the butterscotch pie that drops asgores health and attack plus healing you and the cinnamon bunnies are a cheap healing item that you can stock up on.

Comment: He's asking where to get the healing items not what he should use.